# Cannot zoom tkinter PhotoImage: _tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I have a canvas that has a width of w and a height of h. I'm trying to fit my (1000 x 800) image on it using `image = image.zoom(w).subsample(800)`. But it's giving me the error: `_tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer`. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `zoom`, the first parameter specifies how much to *multiply* each pixel by. If you only provide an `x` value, the `y` value will be the same as the `x` value. Thus, if `w` is 1000, `zoom(x)` will attempt to create an image that is one million pixels wide by 800,000 pixels tall. That's nearly a terabyte of image data.